How does the device tree really work for embedded systems?
From what I understood the old fashion style of probing a linux kernel module (for a platform character device for instance) can be resumed as follow:

Device registration in the VFS
Driver registration in the VFS
If there is a name match between platform device/driver-> probe function is called

This method is one of the last being checked in the platform_match function which bind platform device to platform driver.
static int platform_match(struct device *dev, struct device_driver *drv)
{
    struct platform_device *pdev = to_platform_device(dev);
    struct platform_driver *pdrv = to_platform_driver(drv);

    /* When driver_override is set, only bind to the matching driver */
    if (pdev->driver_override)
        return !strcmp(pdev->driver_override, drv->name);

    /* Attempt an OF style match first */
    if (of_driver_match_device(dev, drv))
        return 1;

    /* Then try ACPI style match */
    if (acpi_driver_match_device(dev, drv))
        return 1;

    /* Then try to match against the id table */
    if (pdrv->id_table)
        return platform_match_id(pdrv->id_table, pdev) != NULL;

    /* fall-back to driver name match */
    return (strcmp(pdev->name, drv->name) == 0);
}

Nowadays we can achieve the same result also with the devicetree.
However I was wondering if the 3 steps that I mentionned earlier are also applied with this method. How does it work behind the hood ?
So will it be :

Kernel register all devices in the VFS with "okay status" with their compatible property in the device tree for each node (at boot ?)
Registration of the driver in the VFS when insmod is called against
the module
If there is a "compatible match" -> probe function is called

I am aware that for each associated device tree node: a struct platform_device is generated by the kernel, device tree information (properties) will populate of_node of the struct device_node
But what happens next once these information are retrieved ? How does the device tree really work ?

"From what I understood the old fashion style of probing ..." - If you had studied the boot log of a Linux kernel, you would never come up with such a scheme. The device drivers have to be (and are) probed & initialized before the root filesystem is mounted & "VFS" can be accessed.

Search the web for the (PDF or video) presentation "Device Tree for Dummies".

When the kernel is starting up, unflatten_device_tree() ("drivers/of/fdt.c") will be called to unpack the dtb as a tree of struct device_nodes. Later, of_platform_default_platform_init() ("drivers/of/platform.c") will be called to create the platform buses (using of_default_bus_match_table[] to match compatible strings such as "simple-bus") and the platform devices on those buses.

@IanAbbott put it as an answer so I can accept it.
